# $\operatorname{fr}(F)= F$, if $F$ is a set without cluster points.

Tags: general-topology

I was reading the following [metric spaces all of whose decompositions are metric](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-021-01/S0002-9939-1969-0239562-9/S0002-9939-1969-0239562-9.pdf) and in (a) $\Rightarrow$ (d) I have problems about the "clearly $\operatorname{fr}(F)=F$".

One side is easy, since $F$ is closed, $\operatorname{fr}(F)\subset F$ it is the other implication is what I have problems. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the fact that $F = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots\}$ has no cluster point in the set $X_0$.

In particular, any element $x_i\in F$ is not a cluster point.  This implies that there is a neighborhood $U_{x_i}$ of $x_i$ that does not contain any other elements of $F$.  The same is then true of $V \cap U_{x_i}$ for any neighborhood $V$ of $x_i$.  Since $x_i$ is not isolated we conclude that this intersection contains at least one element not in $F$.  The same is true of $V$ as well, so we are done.

Comment: I think $V\cap U_{x_i}$ would be $ U_{x_i}=V\cap X_0$

Comment: I don't see why $V \subset U_{x_i}$ would hold for arbitrary neighborhoods $V$.